# Entity Framework Core keeps adding AlterColumn in each new migration for a string array property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core and I've noticed that every time I add a new migration, the migration script includes an AlterColumn operation for a specific string[] property in my model class named CustomTab. The property in question is MyColumn, and it is defined as follows:

```cs
public string[] MyColumn { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();
```

I've already set a default value for it, but each migration still includes this operation, both in the `Up` and `Down` methods:

```cs
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string[]>(
    name: "MyColumn",
    table: "CustomTabs",
    type: "text[]",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: new string[0],
    oldClrType: typeof(string[]),
    oldType: "text[]",
    oldDefaultValue: new string[0]);
```

Here's how I've configured the property in my DbContext:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomTab>()
    .Property(b => b.MyColumn)
    .HasDefaultValue(Array.Empty<string>());
```

Even if I do a fresh migration with no changes, I'll see this in the Up and Down migration files.

Does anyone know why EF Core keeps adding this AlterColumn operation for the same property and how I can prevent this?

Comment: This is using `EF Core 6`

Comment: Maybe issue with ValueComparer [Overriding the default comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-comparers?tabs=ef5#overriding-the-default-comparer). Not sure that is used for generating migrations.

Comment: Has to be something specific to PostgreSQL provider (npgsql), since AFAIK it's the only one supporting array type properties (like `string[]`), so may be ask on their issue tracker?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the issue was being caused as I as setting the default value twice.

Once here:

```cs
 = Array.Empty<string>();
```

And once here:

```cs
.HasDefaultValue(Array.Empty<string>());
```

I'm not convinced with this answer so happy to leave it open, but wanted to leave my findings for future people.